# How can I get TOKEN value from an ASYNC config service in JwtStrategy's super call in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, aws-secrets-manager

I want to get the TOKEN's value from an ASYNC config service in JwtStrategy's constructor super.

For example:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authConfig: AuthConfig) {
        super({token: await authConfig.getConfig.jwtToken});
    }
}
```

I am using AWS Secret Manager for storing sensitive values.

Here is my config file:

```
async getConfig() {
        var sm = await SecretManager();
        
        if('POOL_ID' in sm && sm.POOL_ID !== undefined) {
            return {
                region: envConfig.AWS_REGION,
                userPoolId: sm.POOL_ID,
                clientId: sm.APP_CLIENT_ID,
                jwtToken: sm.jwtToken,
            }
        }
}
```

**PS: I am forbidden to store the config variables in a .js or .ts file or even in .env file directly. I am only allowed to get the values from secret manager only. I've debugged and checked that I am getting correct values in authConfig only this is I can not use it in constructors.**

Comment: What's the error/unexpected behavior you get?

Answer (score 2):

You can't await in a constructor, so I think you need to have the config object injected.

You can make an AUTH_CONFIG [useFactory provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory) that makes the call to secrets manager and returns the config object containing the token. It'll need to be an [asynchronous provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/async-providers) to await the secrets manager call. On app startup, NestJS will wait for the config to be fetched so it can provide the results to`JwtStrategy`.